# Find the series of $e^x$ at $-\infty $

Tags: real-analysis

I'm trying to find the series of $e^x$ at $-\infty $. I know that to find the serie of $f$ at $-\infty $, I compute the series around $0^-$ of $g(u):=f(1/u)$, but here I have difficulties since all derivative look to be $0$.

Comment: Is that necessarily a bad thing? What would you say the limit is as $e^x$ goes to negative infinity.

Comment: For any $\alpha>0$, $e^{-x}\le \frac{1}{x^{\alpha}}$ for "sufficiently large" $x$.

Comment: then the series is null ? But what would be the radius of convergence ? Because I can't right $\lim_{n\to\infty }\frac{0}{0}$.